# Google Maps check if circle area is visible within map boundaries

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Map which contains a circle area.

I want to know if the circle is currently visible within the map's boundaries.

What I found so far is to check whether the **center** of the circle is within the boundaries, but I want to check for the whole circle and not only it's center.

My code that checks if the map's current center is within the boundaries of the circle is this:

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() 
            {                    
                var circleBounds = circle.getBounds();
                console.log(circleBounds.contains(map.getCenter()));
            });
```

So what i want is something like this, which of course is not correct:

```
circleBounds.contains(map.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Determine what the northmost, southmost, westmost, and eastmost LATLNGs of the circle are. You can find this given the circle radius
2. Determine if all points are inside the viewport bounds
3. If true, then yes, the circle must be viewable!

and you really should go back to your old questions and ACCEPT them (click on the check mark outline next to the best answer). This is how you show your appreciation for the hard work your answerers provided.

Comment: He's saying he wants to check if the map is inside the circle, not if the circle is inside the map. Doesn't make much sense to me, but what do I know?  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question - dinosaur-old in internet years - but if you're comparing two bounds, then the following holds *a fortiori*, *n'est-ce pas*?:

```
if(a.getBounds().contains(b.getBounds().getNorthEast()) 
&& a.getBounds().contains(b.getBounds().getSouthWest()))
{console.log('B is within A... Bounds are RECTANGLES: \
              You only need to test two \ 
              diagonally-opposing corners')};
```

That's because for a rectangle R, SW is (`max(x),min(y)`); NE is (`min(x),max(y)`) - and therefore all (`x,y`) in R are covered by the test.

I sure hope that's the case - it's how I do all my bounds comparisons...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tina CG Hoehr.

Just in case anyone else wants this, here is the code for my question:

```
// Get the bounds
var circleBounds = circle.getBounds();      
var ne = circleBounds.getNorthEast(); // LatLng of the north-east corner
var sw = circleBounds.getSouthWest();
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng());
var se = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng());

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() 
{                    
    var mapBounds = map.getBounds();

    // Log whether the circle is inside or outside of the map bounds
    if(mapBounds.contains(ne))
    {
        console.log("northeast is viewable");
    }
    if(mapBounds.contains(sw))
    {
        console.log("southwest is viewable");
    }
    if(mapBounds.contains(nw))
    {
        console.log("northwest is viewable");
    }
    if(mapBounds.contains(se))
    {
        console.log("southeast is viewable");
    }
});
```